# Why not successful " HTTP GET request with socket "?

Tags: java, android, sockets, http, get

I want to send GET message at my Android application. After I want to receive GET response as 200 OK. But I didn't accomplish. I received 408 Request Time-outDate or nothing. Can you help me?

```
    String requestmsg = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    requestmsg += "Host: www.ktu.edu.tr\r\n";
    requestmsg += "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
    requestmsg += "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
    requestmsg += "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW 64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36\r\n";
    requestmsg += "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\r\n";
    requestmsg += "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6\r\n";


    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    BufferedReader dis = null;
    try {

        Log.d("ClientActivity", "Connecting...");
        String addr = InetAddress.getByName("www.ktu.edu.tr").getHostAddress().toString();
        Socket socket = new Socket(addr, 80);
        String data = "";

        try {
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");

            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            dos.write(requestmsg.getBytes());
            Log.i("ClientActivity", "RequestMsg Sent");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((data = dis.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(data);
            }
            Log.i("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");
            Log.i("ClientActivity", "C: Received " + sb.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);

        }

        socket.close();
        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Sockets require some effort; you might prefer a different approach. A standard JSE one would be URL.openConnection.)

Specify the encoding, otherwise it is the default enocding - not portable.

```
new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "Windows-1252"));
```

The same for the reverse direction:

```
requestmsg.getBytes("Windows-1252")
```

This is Windows Latin-1, which browsers will accept even if the more limited Latin-1 "ISO-8859-1" is specified. Check the encoding later.

The sending header can better not say it is prepared to use compression:

```
//requestmsg += "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\r\n";
```

And close the request headers with an empty line:

```
requestmsg += "\r\n";
```

A BufferedOutputStream is more appropriate that a DataOutputStream IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

First, you forgot to finish the request properly by including another `\r\n` line at the end.

Second, you are reading everything you get from the server without determining how long the response actually is.

Please, use either a HTTP library, or learn to properly use the HTTP protocol by studying [the HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you need as others already told you an ending `requestmsg += "\r\n";`

You better remove line `requestmsg += "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\r\n";` as `readLine()` cannot handle zip content.

But also then your code causes for a `SocketTimeoutException`. You should catch that separately.

Your code is ok if do a get to a server of mine and also when used with `String host = "nl3.php.net";`